# How to create sript for DB migration using OpenUpgrade for Odoo 16?

Tags: odoo, odoo-16, openupgrade

I am trying to create a migration script for `stock_account` module using OpeUpgrade for Odoo 16 version.
There is only a `upgrade_analysis.txt` in the folder. Here is the content.

> ---Models in module 'stock_account'---
> ---Fields in module 'stock_account'---
> stock_account / account.move.line        / is_anglo_saxon_line (boolean) : DEL 
> stock_account / account.move.line        / stock_valuation_layer_ids (one2many): NEW relation: stock.valuation.layer 
> stock_account / stock.valuation.layer    / account_move_line_id (many2one): NEW relation: account.move.line 
> stock_account / stock.valuation.layer    / price_diff_value (float)      : NEW 
> ---XML records in module 'stock_account'--- 
> NEW ir.actions.act_window: stock_account.stock_valuation_layer_report_action 
> NEW ir.ui.view: stock_account.product_product_stock_tree_inherit_stock_account 
> NEW ir.ui.view: stock_account.stock_valuation_layer_report_tree 
> NEW ir.ui.view: stock_account.view_stock_quantity_history_inherit_stock_account \

Here, the line
`stock_account / account.move.line        / is_anglo_saxon_line (boolean) : DEL \` indicated that the field is removed in the Odoo16.
Do i need to write a script to delete the field? if yes how can i do it? is there any pre-build function or syntax by OpeUpgrade?

Comment: The question is far too broad to answer here. I recommend looking at the OpenUpgrade documentation and then using examples of existing migration scripts in [OCB](https://github.com/OCA/OCB/tree/16.0) as a basis.

Comment: @CZoellner , i went through the OpenUpgrade document, I didn't find anything related to deleting a field/column. But they have a document regarding the Field renaming.